# New security threat to Magento caused by it using jQuery-File-Upload?

Tags: magento2, jquery, security, file-upload

Magento 2 uses the [Blueimp jQuery File Upload Plugin v5.16.4](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/web/jquery/fileUploader/jquery.fileupload.js) which has recently been identified at posing a [security risk](https://blog.alertlogic.com/emerging-threat-blueimp-jquery-file-upload-crops-up-again/) to web applications which use it.

Is this an issue for Magento and should this file be patched or replaced with a more recent version?

I see there is some PHP validation prohibiting uploading of certain file types (see exampled below) so perhaps it's not required?

- [Magento\Framework\File\Uploader::_validateFile()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/File/Uploader.php#L300)
- [Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader::saveFileToTmpDir()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ImageUploader.php#L237)
- [Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage::uploadFile()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php#L481)
- [Magento\ProductVideo\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Gallery\RetrieveImage::validateRemoteFileExtensions()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/ProductVideo/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Gallery/RetrieveImage.php#L162)

Also, the [blueimp patch](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/commit/aeb47e51c67df8a504b7726595576c1c66b5dc2f) for fixing this is for a file which Magento does not seem to use.